# Kubernetes pods went to 0/2 during a node pool upgrade even though disruption budgets were set to min of 50%. Why?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm upgrading some AKS clusters for an app and have been testing out the `az aks nodepool upgrade` `--max-surge` flag to speed up the process.  Our prod environment has 50+ nodes, and at the clocked speed per node I have seen on our lowers I estimate prod will take 9+ hours to complete.  On one of the lower upgrades I ran a max surge at 50% which did help a little bit on speed, and all deployments kept a minimum available pods of 50%.

For this latest upgrade I tried out a max surge of 100%.  Which spun up 6 new nodes(6 current nodes in the pool) on the correct version....but then it migrated every deployment/pod at the same time and took everything down to 0/2 pods.  Before I started this process I made sure to have a pod disruption budget for every single deployment set at min available of 50%.  This has worked on all of my other upgrades, except this one, which to me means the 100% surge is the cause.

I just can't figure out why my minimum available percentage was ignored. Below are the descriptions of an example PDB, and the corresponding deployment.

Pod disruption budget:

```
Name:           myapp-admin                                                                                            
Namespace:      front-svc                                                                                               
Min available:  50%                                                                                                     
Selector:       role=admin                                                                                              
Status:                                                                                                                 
    Allowed disruptions:  1                                                                                             
    Current:              2                                                                                             
    Desired:              1                                                                                             
    Total:                2                                                                                             
Events:
```

Deployment(snippet):

```
Name:                   myapp-admin                                                                                   
Namespace:              front-svc                                                                                      
CreationTimestamp:      Wed, 26 May 2021 16:17:00 -0500                                                                
Labels:                 <none>                                                                                         
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 104                                                         
Selector:               agency=myorg,app=myapp,env=uat,organization=myorg,role=admin                                      
Replicas:               2 desired | 2 updated | 2 total | 2 available | 0 unavailable                                  
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate                                                                                  
MinReadySeconds:        15                                                                                             
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 1 max surge                                                               
Pod Template:                                                                                                          
  Labels:       agency=myorg                                                                                             
                app=myapp                                                                                             
                buildnumber=1234                                                                               
                env=uat                                                                                                
                organization=myorg                                                                                       
                role=admin                                                                                             
  Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2022-03-12T09:00:11Z                                                
  Containers:                                                                                                          
   myapp-admin-ctr:
```

Is there something obvious I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The node pool probably doesn't care about distribution budged as its not really a kubernetes native thing. If there is no node, it's in involuntary distribution, against which a disruption budget cannot protect you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... a max surge value of 100% provides the fastest possible upgrade
> process (doubling the node count) but also causes **all nodes** in the
> node pool to be drained simultaneously.

From the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/upgrade-cluster#customize-node-surge-upgrade). You may want to consider lower down your max surge.